# Regex to match a digicode (digit, star and sharp)

Tags: javascript, regex

Could anyone please help me writing a regex that I will use to validate a field (representing a digicode) in javascript that has to match the following criterias?

- needs to have 4 to 6 numbers (0 to 9)
- needs to have 1 * (star) or 1 # (sharp) either at the beginning or at the end

So the following works:

- 1234*
- *12345
- 56789#
- #456789

And the following doesn't work:

- 1234
- 1*234
- *1234*
- *1234#
- 1234*#
- abcde

Many thanks!!

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? Getting the value of the input field? Creating the regular expression? Using the regular expression in JavaScript? The expression itself is quite simple and http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good start (also with respect to JavaScript).

Comment: @FelixKling I'm trying to validate a field (as it's says in the question) i.e. a user types in something and I have to check it's correct. I spent an hour on that website before asking but couldn't figure out anything...

Comment: But the overall problem consists of multiple parts: (a) Starting the validation. (b) Getting the input value. (c) Validating the value with a regular expression. What of these do you know? Because all the answers are just giving you the regular expression, which you can easily create by yourself after having a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: @FelixKling You're right. I've edited slightly the question to make it clearer. I'm fine with the javascript process. Just the regex was needed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:[*#]\d{4,6}|\d{4,6}[*#])$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3126e)

You may want to read some basics about regex: [What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4) (my own blog post) everything I used here is covered there.

Answer (score 2):

```
var s,
    rg1=/^[*#]\d{4,6}$/,
    rg2=/^\d{4,6}[*#]$/;

s="1234*"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="*12345"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="56789#"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="#456789"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));

s="1234"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="1*234"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="*1234*"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="*1234#"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="1234*#"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
s="abcde"; console.info(rg1.test(s)||rg2.test(s));
```

Comment: You can probably add that OR operation in the regex itself - just put them both together in one pattern and add a (single) pipe between.

Comment: @zladuric: you're right, but I do not post this solution because it's very similar with others.

Comment: You have a point there. <trol> The OP could try if (s === "*1111" || s === "#1111" || s = "*1112"... </trol>

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this can be more optimal.
Tested in node.js:

```
var x = new RegExp(/^[*#]\d{4,6}$|^\d{4,6}[*#]$/);
```

Comment: Working version: var x = new RegExp(/^([*#])(\d){4,6}$|^(\d){4,6}([*#])$/);

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you;

```
var expression = /^([*#]?\d{4,6}|\d{4,6}[*#]?)$/;
```

And matching where there always has to be at least on * or # i.e. not just 1234

```
var expression = /^([*#]\d{4,6}|\d{4,6}[*#])$/;
```

Comment: Doesn't this validate 1234 without * or # at all?

Comment: Ah yes my mistake, I misread and have to remove the ?'s... I'll edit the main post